# If I burn a dvd with files on mac, is it going to be readable on another systems?

Tags: mac, filesystems, iso-image, hfs, dvd-burning

I don't want to burn a DVD with files that is only going to be read by newer Windows versions, and not by a Linux box.

Can I trust on Mac's bultin DVD recorder in Finder in creating fully compatible DVD-Rs like all recorders in the planet in a Windows system do, or am I going to have a 'hybrid' Mac proprietary format and would make a CD-R useless when trying to use for example in my car system with some MP3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the Finder does, so I don't trust it... However, a good piece of software is Burn:

http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html

It's straight forward and free.

Comment: An interesting solution, I would like to know if it's possible to just use Finder and create a fully compatible dvdr. If not possible, your solution is going to be a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the UDF format when burning your disc (v1.02 for compatibility), this can be read by all Mac and Windows OSes released in about the last 5 years, maybe more. If you have the option, use Joliet and ISO 9660 too, this will ensure compatibility with all OSes for about the last 15-20 years.

From a quick search, it appears that Finder burns a hybrid ISO 9660/HFS filesystem, this should be able to be read on Windows machines but ISO 9660 is very old and restrictive, I suggest finding some better burning software. Burn, as Huw suggested, is free, so you might want to try that.